# Why is my VBA code skipping lines when I run it, but not when I step through it?==

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Below is the code I wrote. I am trying to have an Excel model I built create a power point from an existing PowerPoint template. Currently, I am just trying to make sure it can go through once and fill in the necessary information, but eventually I will want it to loop and create a longer PowerPoint when given multiple inputs. Before adding that, I need to have this code work. When I step through the code pressing F8, if works perfectly and executes as it should. When I press "Run," however, it skips sections and posts information from the excel file in the wrong locations. Is there any way to make it run more efficiently so that it no longer skips, and so that I will be able to have it run more complex code later?

Thanks!

```
Public Sub DevOppDeck()

    Set ppApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
    Set ppPres = ppApp.ActivePresentation

    'Pick your DMA

    userInput = InputBox("Please type in a DMA ID", "Create a Development Opportunity Deck")

        Worksheets(2).Range("b4") = userInput

    Dim DMAName As Variant

        Set findName = Worksheets("vlookups").Range("AD2:AG211")
        DMAName = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(userInput, findName, 4, False)

    'Rename Deck

    slidenum = 1
        Set ppslide = ppPres.Slides(slidenum)
        ppslide.Select

    ppslide.Shapes("PPT_Title").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = DMAName & Space(1) & "Development Opportunity"
    ppslide.Shapes("PPT_Date").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "January 1900"

    'Change data for DMA proposal tables

    slidenum = 4
        Set ppslide = ppPres.Slides(slidenum)
        ppslide.Select

            'Competitor benchmark table
            Set compBench = ppslide.Shapes("Comp_Benchmark")

                Worksheets(2).Range("E7:I16").Copy

                compBench.Table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.Select
                    ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableDestinationTableStyle")

            'Market demographics table
            Set marketDem = ppslide.Shapes("Market_Dem")

                Worksheets(2).Range("L7:M12").Copy

                marketDem.Table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.Select
                    ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableDestinationTableStyle")

            'Market statistics table
            Set marketStats = ppslide.Shapes("Market_Stats")

                Worksheets(2).Range("P7:Q12").Copy

                marketStats.Table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.Select
                    ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableDestinationTableStyle")

    'Change data for Opportunity Summary

    slidenum = 5
       Set ppslide = ppPres.Slides(slidenum)
       ppslide.Select

            'Competitor benchmark table
            Set compOpps = ppslide.Shapes("Competitor_Opps")

                Worksheets(2).Range("G20:G22").Copy

                compOpps.Table.Cell(2, 5).Shape.Select
                    ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableDestinationTableStyle")

                Worksheets(2).Range("H20").Copy

                compOpps.Table.Cell(5, 5).Shape.Select
                    ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableDestinationTableStyle")

            'Seed opportunities table
            Set seedOpps = ppslide.Shapes("Trade_Area_Seeds")

                Worksheets(2).Range("I20").Copy

                seedOpps.Table.Cell(2, 3).Shape.Select
                    ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableDestinationTableStyle")

                Worksheets(2).Range("I20").Copy

                seedOpps.Table.Cell(5, 3).Shape.Select
                    ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableDestinationTableStyle")

End Sub
```

Comment: Excel to PowerPoint is notoriously troublesome - you may need to add some `Application.Wait`s in there before/after you copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your macro more reliable you would need to check that copying and selecting is finished before pasting the data with `ExecuteMso`. For the clipboard you would need to clear it first and then try to `.copy` until the clipboard is filled. Then for the shape selection it is the same: Try to `select` it until it is really selected. For both cases a while loop could be used (stay away from infinite loops, of course ;-) ). For sake of brevity and usability you could put this into a separate function.